# Update panel gridview asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, updatepanel

Can you help me with this. When I click on ID 1,2.... take the ID from query string and  display those names where id from query string is equal on id_proba in the other table. This is ok and show me. Now i like when i click on ID 1,2.. in GridView1 to refresh only gridview 2 not all page. Need gridview to put in Ajax Update Panel. I put gridview2 in Update panel but don't know what to write in code?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />

        <asp:HyperLinkField 
  DataTextField="id" 
  DataTextFormatString=" {0}" 
  DataNavigateUrlFields="id" HeaderText="id"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="WebForm1.aspx?ID={0}"   />
    </Columns>
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
    <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
    <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
    <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
</asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProbaConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Proba1] WHERE [id] = @id" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Proba1] ([name]) VALUES (@name)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [id] FROM [Proba1]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Proba1] SET [name] = @name WHERE [id] = @id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id_proba" HeaderText="id_proba" 
                    SortExpression="id_proba" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProbaConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id_proba], [name] FROM [proba3] WHERE ([id_proba] = @id_proba)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id_proba" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: you can do it using Gridview's selectedindex change event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh the update panel by clicking in `GridView1` you could add a javascript onclick handler to the links in `GirdView1`.
In this event handler you could refresh the update panel by calling `__doPostBack`. You could use jQuery to add the eventhandler to all a tags in the grid as follows:

```
<script>
   $(function() {
         $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> a").bind('click', function() {
             refreshUpdatePanel();
          });
   });

  function refreshUpdatePanel()
  {
    __doPostBack('UpdatePanel1', '');
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your grids are not too big, put them both in the same update panel.
That way you will not have to write any code to get `GridView2` update on clicks in `GridView1`.

Like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
       <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
            onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged">
            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />

                <asp:HyperLinkField 
          DataTextField="id" 
          DataTextFormatString=" {0}" 
          DataNavigateUrlFields="id" HeaderText="id"
          DataNavigateUrlFormatString="WebForm1.aspx?ID={0}"   />
            </Columns>
            <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F5F7FB" />
            <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#6D95E1" />
            <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E9EBEF" />
            <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4870BE" />
        </asp:GridView>

        <br />
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id_proba" HeaderText="id_proba" 
                    SortExpression="id_proba" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProbaConnectionString %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT [id_proba], [name] FROM [proba3] WHERE ([id_proba] = @id_proba)">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="id_proba" QueryStringField="ID" Type="Int32" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProbaConnectionString %>" 
    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Proba1] WHERE [id] = @id" 
    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Proba1] ([name]) VALUES (@name)" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [name], [id] FROM [Proba1]" 
    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Proba1] SET [name] = @name WHERE [id] = @id">
    <DeleteParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </DeleteParameters>
    <InsertParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
    </InsertParameters>
    <UpdateParameters>
        <asp:Parameter Name="name" Type="String" />
        <asp:Parameter Name="id" Type="Int32" />
    </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Comment: i know, but i need to do it that way as I wrote above

Answer (score 0):

Look at this solution of nested grid
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38046/Nested-GridView-No-JavaScripts