# Gridview hyperlink click event refresh ajax update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, visual-studio-2010, updatepanel

How can i do that, when i click on ID in Gridview1 which i make like hyperlink field to refresh only Ajax Update Panel, not all page? What i need in code?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
    DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" CellPadding="4" 
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" 
    onselectedindexchanged="GridView1_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="232px">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />

        <asp:HyperLinkField 
  DataTextField="id" 
  DataTextFormatString=" {0}" 
  DataNavigateUrlFields="id" HeaderText="id"
  DataNavigateUrlFormatString="WebForm1.aspx?ID={0}"   />
    </Columns>
```

This is the code for Update Panel, where when i click on ID in GridView1 refresh Update Panel with Gridview2:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<br />
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" runat="server">

    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="id_proba" HeaderText="id_proba" 
                    SortExpression="id_proba" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="name" HeaderText="name" SortExpression="name" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource2" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProbaConnectionString %>" 

        </asp:SqlDataSource>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Update panel gridview asp.net C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297095/update-panel-gridview-asp-net-c-sharp)

Comment: one friend tell me this:HyperLink doesn't do PostBack. It does a new page load. If you want the UpdatePanel the GridView is in to refresh you need to do a PostBack. For instance by using a LinkButton in a TemplateField instead of HyperLink.

Comment: That is correct. Which is why you have to write javascript if you want it to do a postback.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the HyperLink as a Postback trigger on Every postback manually in the Page_Load(). Maybe that will solve the problem..